# python: parse text config and store

Tags: python, parsing, config

I have a config file in following format:

```
# some comment
keyword1=value1
keyword2=value2
...
```

where values could be text strings (e.g. /usr/local/lib/...), numbers, IP addresses (10.10.10.1/24). I'd like to be able to parse the configuration and store internally (may be as dictionary).

I'm newbie with `python`, in `bash` I used `source my_config.cfg`.

what is the right way parse/store config options in python? As a newbie, I'd start with:

```
with open("my_config.cfg", "rt") as f:
   ...
```

but what do I do next, call `f.redline()` in a loop until end of file?

Comment: python has a built-in cfgparser. Check this https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: @Sifat, thanks for link. However it seems it has very good support of INI-type configs, mine is slightly different, Can I adapt `configparser` to understand custom configs?

Comment: „mine is slightly different“ Can you clarify how it is different? It is hard to say how to work with an unknown format.

Comment: I am not sure. But you can see my answer below.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, _„mine is slightly different“ Can you clarify how it is different? It is hard to say how to work with an unknown format._  It's in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def parse_cfg(filename):
    data = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("#"):
                continue
            if "=" in line:
                key, value = line.split("=")
                data[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    return data
```

You can add custom logic to this.